# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }

Tags: android, google-voice

The exception was thrown in the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
      RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);.
```

I've googled and found that it's because of [the voice search app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch) from google is missing on the device I am using. and I could solve the problem by installing the app manually, but how could I get the apk installed programly, like import some library or other~
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question's link to "the voice search app" is currently broken (404).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

open link of the application(which you want to use) in web view

as

```
try{
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
      RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);.
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,   Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=APP_PACKAGE_NAME"));
startActivity(browserIntent);

}
```

replace APP_PACKAGE_NAME in https://market.android.com/details?id=APP_PACKAGE_NAME with the voice rcognition applicatio package name on market

Comment: thanks for your reply vipin, but could I add the voice module as part of my apk.

Comment: yes you can for sure
but for that you have to write down whole code for this on your own

Comment: @vipin When you say APP_PACKAGE_NAME, are there default ones you know of?  I mean it works fine on my other devices, but for Sony Experia Mini the speech recognition doesn't work.  So I would like to point the user to the default speech recognition from Google.

Comment: Igor there are not the things like default for voice search from google but you can use app from google to meet you requirement please try this com.google.android.voicesearch

Comment: This package, voicesearch, is not available anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Vipin's solution works.
I personally used this as my APP_PACKAGE_NAME:
`com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`

So to recap the full solution you would do the following: (I modified it a little to first try the `market://` scheme first and then fallback on the `https://` if that fails.)

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
      RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);.
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    String appPackageName = "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox";
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
}
```