# Android - How to take input in speech and convert that into text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, voice-recognition

i am trying the as given on link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/
But every time it is throwing the following exception.

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }

What should i do ?

Thank You.

Comment: What is your logcat output that shows the error? That will help us on giving you an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  What exception does it throw?  The more info you can provide in a question, generally the better an answer you can get.

Comment: Which exception?Show your logcat view here

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }

Comment: The above error is there in log cat

Comment: you might want to try the solution given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275001/908821. it will prompt the user to download the speech recognition app if it does not exist on the device.